# How to clean a string to get value_counts for words of interest by date?

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I have the following data generated from a `groupby('Datetime')` and `value_counts()`

```
Datetime        0          
01/01/2020  Paul            8
            03              2
01/02/2020  Paul            2
            10982360967     1
01/03/2020  religion        3
                           ..
02/28/2020  l              18
02/29/2020  Paul           78
            march          22
03/01/2020  church         63
            l              21
```

I would like to remove a specific name (in this case I would like to remove 'Paul') and all the numbers (03, 10982360967 in this specific example). I do not know why there is a character 'l' as I had tried to remove stopwords including alphabet (and numbers). 
Do you know how I could *further* clean this selection?

Expected output to avoid confusion:

```
Datetime        0          
01/03/2020  religion        3
                           ..
02/29/2020  march          22
03/01/2020  church         63
```

I removed Paul, 03, 109..., and l.

Raw data:

```
Datetime        Corpus          
01/03/2020      Paul: examples of religion
01/03/2020      Paul:shinto is a religion 03
01/03/2020      don't talk to me about religion, Paul 03
...
02/29/2020     march is the third month of the year 10982360967
02/29/2020     during march, there are some cold days.
...
03/01/2020     she is at church right now
...
```

I cannot put all the raw data as I have more than 100 sentences.

The code I used is:

```
df.Corpus.groupby('Datetime').value_counts().groupby('Datetime').head(2)
```

Since I got a Key error, I had to edit the code as follows:

```
df.set_index('Datetime').Corpus.groupby('Datetime').value_counts().groupby('Datetime').head(2)
```

To extract the words I used `str.extractall`

Comment: The most likely thing is that the number you see are object as dtype. Why don't you remove them before the group by?

Comment: Are you asking how to drop rows?

Comment: For numbers and characters I had tried but it seems not working as I expected. For the specific word I wanted to see if it was relevant or not for the list, so probably I would need to drop it after the selection. But maybe you are right

Comment: words in that selection, in order to exclude those from the count. (like doing another one, but without those words)

Comment: I added an expected output.

Comment: It will be better if you share the raw data sample and the code used to produce this output.

Comment: I updated the question with raw data and code. @TrentonMcKinney. I hope this can help. Let me know if it does not help and you need more info. Thanks

Comment: I had to edit the code as I got a key error because of Datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Cleaning strings is a multi-step process

### Create dataframe

```py
import pandas as pd
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import string

# data and dataframe
data = {'Datetime': ['01/03/2020', '01/03/2020', '01/03/2020', '02/29/2020', '02/29/2020', '03/01/2020'],
        'Corpus': ['Paul: Examples of religion',
                   'Paul:shinto is a religion 03',
                   "don't talk to me about religion, Paul 03",
                   'march is the third month of the year 10982360967',
                   'during march, there are some cold days.',
                   'she is at church right now']}

test = pd.DataFrame(data)
test.Datetime = pd.to_datetime(test.Datetime)

|    | Datetime            | Corpus                                           |
|---:|:--------------------|:-------------------------------------------------|
|  0 | 2020-01-03 00:00:00 | Paul: Examples of religion                       |
|  1 | 2020-01-03 00:00:00 | Paul:shinto is a religion 03                     |
|  2 | 2020-01-03 00:00:00 | don't talk to me about religion, Paul 03         |
|  3 | 2020-02-29 00:00:00 | march is the third month of the year 10982360967 |
|  4 | 2020-02-29 00:00:00 | during march, there are some cold days.          |
|  5 | 2020-03-01 00:00:00 | she is at church right now                       |
```

### Clean `Corpus`

- Add extra words to the `remove_words` list

  - They should be lowercase
- Some cleaning steps could be combined, but I do not recommend that

  - Step-by-step makes it easier to determine if you've made a mistake
- This is a small example of text cleaning.

  - There are entire books on the subject.
  - There's not context analysis

    - `example = 'We march to the church in March.'`
    - `value_count` for `'march'` in `example.lower()` is 2

```py
# words to remove
remove_words = list(stopwords.words('english'))
# extra words to remove
additional_remove_words = ['paul', 'shinto', 'examples', 'talk', 'third', 'month', 'year', 'cold', 'days', 'right']
remove_words.extend(additional_remove_words)  # add other words to exclude in lowercase

# punctuation to remove
punctuation = string.punctuation
punc = r'[{}]'.format(punctuation)

test.dropna(inplace=True)  # drop any na rows

# clean text now
test.Corpus = test.Corpus.str.replace('\d+', '')  # remove numbers

test.Corpus = test.Corpus.str.replace(punc, ' ')  # remove punctuation 

test.Corpus = test.Corpus.str.replace('\\s+', ' ')  # remove occurrences of more than one whitespace

test.Corpus = test.Corpus.str.strip()  # remove whitespace from beginning and end of string

test.Corpus = test.Corpus.str.lower()  # convert all to lowercase

test.Corpus = test.Corpus.apply(lambda x: list(word for word in x.split() if word not in remove_words))  # remove words

|    | Datetime            | Corpus       |
|---:|:--------------------|:-------------|
|  0 | 2020-01-03 00:00:00 | ['religion'] |
|  1 | 2020-01-03 00:00:00 | ['religion'] |
|  2 | 2020-01-03 00:00:00 | ['religion'] |
|  3 | 2020-02-29 00:00:00 | ['march']    |
|  4 | 2020-02-29 00:00:00 | ['march']    |
|  5 | 2020-03-01 00:00:00 | ['church']   |
```

### Explode `Corpus` & `groupby`

```py
# explode list
test = test.explode('Corpus')

# dropna incase there are empty rows from filtering
test.dropna(inplace=True)

# groupby
test.groupby('Datetime').agg({'Corpus': 'value_counts'}).rename(columns={'Corpus': 'word_count'})

                     word_count
Datetime   Corpus              
2020-01-03 religion           3
2020-02-29 march              2
2020-03-01 church             1
```