# How to clean dataset with special characters?

Tags: python, pandas

There are a lot of cells with data that looks like this (I'm analyzing an E-Commerce dataset):

```
Mode d'Ã©tÃ© Flare Sleeve Plus Size T-shirt hors de l'Ã©paule
```

How would you recommend that I clean this dataset? I know string replace is an option, but is there a better/more efficient option? I only really need "Flare Sleeve Plus Size T-shirt"

Comment: Maybe some different encoding when reading/importing the data would help.

Comment: [How to clean a string to get value_counts for words of interest by date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62236140)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

`print("Mode d'Ã©tÃ© Flare Sleeve Plus Size T-shirt hors de l'Ã©paule ".encode('WINDOWS-1252').decode())`

Comment: result is: `Mode d'été Flare Sleeve Plus Size T-shirt hors de l'épaule`